# MySQL script is executing commented lines

Tags: mysql

The weirdest thing is happening here. I have a script that creates a bunch of sql tables. Here's a quick example:

```
FileName is create_mydb.sql

    --Drops/Creates table UserGroup
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS UserGroup;
    CREATE TABLE UserGroup (
        user_group_id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
        user_id int,
        group_id int,
        PRIMARY KEY (user_group_id)
    ) ENGINE=INNODB;


    -- Drops/Creates table Group
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Group;
    CREATE TABLE Group (
        group_id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
        group_name varchar(50),
        PRIMARY KEY (group_id)
    ) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

When I run this from the command line like:

```
mysql>\. create_mydb.sql
```

I get errors like this for every comment:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '--Drops/Creates table Group
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL Requires that the double-dash comment format be followed by some whitespace or a control character in order to differentiate your comments from potentially valid syntax.

[9.6. Comment Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comments.html)

> From a “-- ” sequence to the end of the line. In MySQL, the “-- ” (double-dash) comment style requires the second dash to be followed by at least one whitespace or control character (such as a space, tab, newline, and so on). This syntax differs slightly from standard SQL comment syntax, as discussed in Section 1.8.5.5, “'--' as the Start of a Comment”.

[1.8.5.5. '--' as the Start of a Comment](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/ansi-diff-comments.html)

> MySQL Server 3.23.3 and up also supports a variant of the “--” comment style. That is, the “--” start-comment sequence must be followed by a space (or by a control character such as a newline). The space is required to prevent problems with automatically generated SQL queries